# Beast Bond Duration

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger

A Gloom Stalker Ranger cast *Beast Bond*. Does it end in 10 minutes, and the beast just leaves? Or does it take 10 minutes of concentration to establish the Bond and gain a companion?

> **Beast Bond**
>
> You establish a telepathic link with one beast you touch that is friendly to you or charmed by you. The spell fails if the beast's Intelligence score is 4 or higher. Until the spell ends, the link is active while you and the beast are within line of sight of each other. Through the link, the beast can understand your telepathic messages to it, and it can telepathically communicate simple emotions and concepts back to you. While the link is active, the beast gains advantage on attack rolls against any creature within 5 feet of you that you can see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spell [Beast Bond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beast-bond) has a casting time of one action. It then lasts for 10 minutes (or until your concentration is broken).

It can only be used on a beast that is already friendly to you or charmed, so that pretty much limits it to either the companion of a Beast Master ranger or requires you to charm an animal first.

After the spell ends the beast is still just an animal that is likely to still be friendly to you or charmed (unless the charm was broken). It will behave as suits its nature - a wild animal will probably just leave when it can.